# How ImageResizer Dynamically change image resolution based on screen size

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, imageresizer

I am using ImageResizer to resize the images and display on the bootstrap layout.
Here I am fixing the image sizes while retrieving them to display the sizes in URL.

Issue is, image quality is lost as dimensions are different for different screen sizes and I am unable to adjust the image which is retrieved to fit exactly to the screen size.

Eg: for 14 inch monitor if size of image is 300*300 which gives perfect quality image, if the same image is viewed in 21 inch monitor the 300*300 image retrieved from imageresizer is loosing quality and getting blurred.

Can some one say what is best solution to retrieve images?

Thanks in advance.
Praveen.

Comment: First you need to do some basic homework on the relationship between screen real estate and pixels. Essentially, you need to be able to swap out a different graphic in case of different conditions. However, in this case you have an abnormal condition--someone has a large monitor but is setting it where it's not giving them a lot of pixels, so you may not be able to detect the fact that it's a large monitor. Usually when people get large monitors it's so they get more pixels.

Answer (score 0):

[Slimmage.js](https://github.com/imazen/slimmage) offers automatic resolution and dpi-switching using the ImageResizer URL API. It is probably the easiest way to achieve what you are looking for, as you just install it and set a CSS max-width on images. Done.

Why this is a problem (like Amy says in the first comment):

Because of high-density displays, browser pixels and screen pixels are not 1-1. Thus you need to use a images-swapping technique like srcset, picture, or Slimmage.js. srcset and picture require polyfills to work on older browsers.

Comment: I have added slimmage.js into my application which has Imageresizer installed,  Issue is image width is not changing dynamically even after installing slimmage and adding slimmage= true in the query parameter, can I know what else I need to do to get this functionality of changing width parameter dynamically to be enabled in my application, also I get an error when I do The plugin ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache doesn't support constructor arguments.
   To support arguments in the <add> element, the plugin must have a public constructor that accepts a NameValueCollection argument.